# rxjava Observable in DialogFragment

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java, android-room, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to add a setMultiChoiceItems to my DialogFragment but I come across some problems. Let me illustrate with simpler example:

I have this DialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                MyViewModel myVM = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
                //MyViewModel load data from database with repository and Dao 
                myVM.getAllItems().subscribe(items -> {
                                builder.setTitle("Title");
                });
                return builder.create();
        }
}
```

I tested it on my emulator. It seems that mostly, the title is not showing when the DialogFragment is created, but occasionally it is shown correctly. Does anyone know the reason? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `getAllItems` is an asynchronous call. So, `builder.setTitle("Title");` is going to get called whenever `getAllItems` is going to get resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way I can get `setTitle` called every time the Dialog is created using asynchronous query?

Comment: Your code is already doing it.